# Restricting select fields with Korma

Tags: sql, clojure, korma

I'm trying to restrict the columns returned from a select query to just one column, but Korma seems to just add the additional column to the default ones instead of using just this one:

`=> (dry-run (select games (fields :white_id)))
dry run :: SELECT "games"."stones", "games"."white_id", "games"."black_id", "games"."white_id" FROM "games" :: []`

For reference:

`=> (dry-run (select games ))
dry run :: SELECT "games"."stones", "games"."white_id", "games"."black_id" FROM "games" :: []`

What I'd like to see as the output is:

`SELECT "games"."white_id" FROM "games";`

Using latest Korma 0.4.0

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported this upstream and it seems to be the expected behaviour (by the Korma developers) for the current version.

I expect the discussion to continue there instead: https://github.com/korma/Korma/issues/251

Answer (score 0):

I checked following

`(use :reload-all 'korma.core)`

=> nil

```
(dry-run (select :users (fields :id)))
```

dry run :: SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" :: []

=> [{nil 1}]

```
(dry-run (select :users))
```

dry run :: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" :: []

=> [{nil 1}]

i am using korma 0.3.1 and it's working fine for me.
check your korma version and reply back if you still have any issue or mention version number in reply

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned I'm using the latest Korma version: 0.4.0. I updated the question now.

Comment: are you still getting same error as mentioned in question?

Comment: It's not an error, but yes the behaviour is the same as in the question since nothing changed. But I've reported this upstream, see my other answer.