# Unable to SELECT COUNT(*) for Korma entity with default fields

Tags: clojure, korma

I am unable to `SELECT COUNT(*)` from an entity I have mapped in Korma.

Here is my entity:

`(declare users responses)
(korma/defentity users
  (korma/entity-fields :id :slack_id :active :token :token_created)
  (korma/many-to-many responses :userresponses))`

And here is my attempt at a `SELECT COUNT(*)`:

`(korma/select
    schema/users
    (korma/fields ["count(*)"])
    (korma/where {:slack_id slack-id}))`

I get this error:

`ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function at character 8
STATEMENT:  SELECT "users"."id", "users"."slack_id", "users"."active", "users"."token", "users"."token_created", count(*) FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."slack_id" = $1)`

It looks like Korma is including my entity fields even though I'm specifying fields to select in this query. How do I override that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825252/restricting-select-fields-with-korma is vaguely similar but relates to default behavior of `(select)` with no fields specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override it per se. Korma query manipulation functions are [always additive](https://github.com/korma/Korma/issues/251#issuecomment-57076713), so specifying fields merely specifies *additional* fields.

To get around this, you can [rewrite this query to select against the `users` table itself](https://github.com/korma/Korma/issues/286#issuecomment-87411156) rather than the Korma entity `users`:

```
(korma/select :users
  (korma/fields ["count(*)"])
  (korma/where {:slack_id slack-id}))
```

But then you'll have to make do without anything else defined in the `users` entity.

Alternatively, you could rewrite this entity to not define any entity-fields, then define a wrapped version of this entity with the desired default fields:

````
(korma/defentity users-raw
  (korma/many-to-many responses :userresponses)))

(def users
  (korma/select
    users-raw
    (korma/fields [:id :slack_id :active :token :token_created])))```
````

Then you can write your normal queries by adding `with`/`where` clauses to this "users" query, and only directly touch `users-raw` when you need to exclude those fields:

```
(-> users (with ...) (where ...) (select))
```